# If (.somthing:contains(text).addClass, if else (:contains(otherText).addClass

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains

Short story: we lost our php guy, until we get a new one I am using this hackey method to accomplish the goal of adding icons to the tr's.

So I got this table that has 4 categories that I want to apply icons, I am trying to write if else statements but not getting the results I want. Here is a dirty version of my code:

```
if ($('.summary:contains("Sharks")').each(function () {
     $(this).parent().children('.category').addClass('shark-icon');
});
elseif ($('.summary:contains("Whale")').each(function () {
     $(this).parent().children('.category').addClass('whale-icon');
});
```

When pulled out of the if statements the works just fine, but I cant seem to get the if else going. Any thoughts?

Comment: you don't need the `if else`. `jQuery` already selects only those ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.summary:contains("Sharks")').siblings('.category').addClass('shark-icon');
$('.summary:contains("Whale")').siblings('.category').addClass('whale-icon');
```

should do.

You don't need the `if else` clause in the first place as the selectors will filter the items and you can add the class to the `tr` directly.

If category is the class on the `td` to which you want to apply the class use the `.siblings` method

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

```
$('.summary').each(function () {
    if($(this).is(':contains("Sharks")')){ 
        $(this).parent().children('.category').addClass('shark-icon');
    } else if($(this).is(':contains("Whale")')){ 
        $(this).parent().children('.category').addClass('whale-icon');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated. This worked great but got to go with the shorter code.